# Exchange body substring in log message

Tags: apache-camel

How to log exchange body substring as message attribute of log component?

I have tried these:

```
<log message="SEND RESPONSE TO WEB SERVICE: Headers:[${headers}]\nBody:[${bodyAs(String).substring(0,1000)}]"/>
<log message="SEND RESPONSE TO WEB SERVICE: Headers:[${headers}]\nBody:[${body.toString().substring(0,1000)}]"/>
```

but none works. First variant is marked as mistake by IDE Camel plugin and does not allow application to start, and the second one throws the exception about calling toString() at null (although body is not).

ps body is really instance of String.

Comment: “Doesn’t work” is not going to get you any answers.

Comment: If body,toString() throws a NullException, then the body must be null, not a String. Have you tried just logging ${body} to see if it is null

Comment: I clearly understand it. So I have checked body value. It is NOT nullable. I have noticed that ${body.toString().substring(0,1000)} works correctly in Camel Java DSL.

Answer (score 1):

Read [this page](https://camel.apache.org/log.html), particularly the section "Full Customization of the Logged Output"

Comment: Yes, I have already read it. But how would you log body substring and some custom message in a single log record?

Comment: Please try something based on the previous suggestions then report back here (with your code) if it doesn't work.